# how to upload 000000001.db file to server by using file transfer api of phonegap?

Tags: cordova

i am uploading 000000001.db file to server by using file transfer api of phonegap but it gives me error 
file not found error code=1
can anyone help me out how to get rid of this thing.

```
function uploadFile() {
    alert('uploading file');
    // Get URI of picture to upload
    var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
   // var imageURI = img.src;

   //"/data/data/com.suave.nexttrainer/app_database/file_0/0000000001.db";
    //i am giving physical address of database of simulator here 
    var imageURI = "/data/data/com.suave.nexttrainer/app_database/file_0/0000000001.db";
 // Verify server has been entered
    server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
    alert('server');
    if (server) {

        // Specify transfer options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        // Transfer picture/file to server
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        alert('ft');
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";              
        }, function(error) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
        }, options);
    }
```

Comment: are you resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) try using

"var imageURI = "file:///data/data/com.suave.nexttrainer/app_database/file_0/0000000001.db";

2) Is com.suave.netxtrainer your app package? Because only that app can read from that directory.

Comment: i do like that but in my log cat it shows this .



02-20 01:50:51.194: E/FileTransfer(1624): {"target":"http:\/\/nextrainer.com\/nexdbbackup\/upload.php","source":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.suave.nexttrainer\/app_database\/file_0\/0000000001.db","code":1}
02-20 01:50:51.194: E/FileTransfer(1624): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.suave.nexttrainer/app_database/file_0/0000000001.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

its the path of sever on which i have to upload the database file "http://nextrainer.com/nexdbbackup/upload.php"

Comment: simon have you any idea of uploading 0000000001.db i.e database file to some server

Comment: simon have you any idea of uploading 00000000001.db i.e database file to some server actually i want to take a backup of database like if device is theft or broken in that condition we should have a backup of our database ..what you say about this ???

Comment: Yes, you can do that but it looks like you have the wrong file path or file name.

Comment: may be iam testing it on simulator in which i know the default path of 00000000000001.db file but in case of device i dont know the path of 0000000001.db file have you any idea how can we fount that path and give that path to server?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald i tried your way it is working in emulator but not in real device any suggestion really helpfull.